# Best browser for testing under Safari Mobile on Linux?

Tags: iphone, linux, testing, webkit

I have an iPhone web app I'm producing on a Linux machine. What's the best browser I can use to most closely mimic the feature-limited version of Safari present on the iPhone? (It's a "slimmed down" version of WebKit, which is more limited than one might think.)

Comment: Having tried to use Konqueror (webkit-based), it is sufficiently different from Mobile Safari that it doesn't given sufficient fidelity to be used as a testing browser.

Comment: My solution for now is to run and old version of Windows Safari on Wine.  I am not yet sure which one best  resembles the current iOS safari browser which IS ABSOLUTELY as you said FAR BEHIND every other browser. Which makes it ( UNFORTUNATELY ) the browser that we are forced to code for now.

Comment: I have since switched to Gnome Web (epiphany browser) and Otter Browser for testing since they are pure webkit 2.0+ and behind enough in CSS3/HTML5 support to be somewhat comparable to safari mobile.  If you open safari mobile on css3test.com you can make a list of experimental features that it does not support.  I have made such a list and will share it if there is enough interest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A used iPod Touch for US$150 (used, in Seattle).  It's either that, or the iPhone simulator running on a Mac.  If one is specifically targeting "iPhone web app", the cost should be budgeted into the project.

Barring that, use desktop Safari.  That will still require a Windows or Mac box.  The rendering engine is the same, so I imagine it's as close as you're going to get on the desktop.

On the other hand, what are the problems you are trying to avoid?  Mobile Safari is pretty good at rendering most web sites I call up. There are guidelines for development, and avoid media such as Flash.  If you don't have the hardware, borrow it for sanity checking when you're done.  That's the route I'd go if I absolutely didn't want to spend the US$150.

Comment: I've got a device; the real issue is the testing/debugging turnaround time. I'd like to be able to develop, test and debug on the same machine, without having to go out to my iPod.

Comment: I am sad that this was selected as the answer.  I am a Linux developer and have this exact issue.  It is trivial to get BigSur running in Qemu on a linux machine and then run an iOS simulator in xcode inside of that but that is NOT the answer.  Any web developer knows that you need a browser to give you instant feedback as you troubleshoot issues.  I have my code window to the right and instantly updating webserver/browser to the left.  This proposed answer is not the answer.  We need a browser that runs on Linux.  I suggest that Chrome 87 is the most feature-close to current iOS safari.

Comment: The reason I suggest Chrome 87 is because it is a sweet spot where display:grid was supported and just before aspect-ratio was implemented.  With further feedback we might get something better but that was the best I could come up with.  There are more issues like border backgrounds and container query scaling that should also be taken into account.